# Making an Ajax call to a partial view after ajax success

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a partial view that contains all my buttons and it needs to display updated values after a form is submitted. At the submission I already have it rendering another partial view, is there a way to make it work where on success of that one being rendered it re-renders. Here is the code I am trying to get to work now based on what I've seen in other places.

jQuery in my view:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#ChangeGrade').click(function (e) {
        var tdata = $('#form1').serialize();
        var origname = $('#HeatGradeDiv').find('input[name="grade"]').first().val();
        var newname = $('#HeatGradeDiv').find('input[name="updatedGrade"]').first().val();
        var heatname = $('#HeatGradeDiv').find('input[name="hiddenHeat"]').first().val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                mCollection: tdata,
                grade: origname,
                updatedGrade: newname,
                hiddenHeat: heatname

            },
            url: '@Url.Action("ChangeGrade","Home")',
            success: function (result) { success(result); }
        });
    });


    function success(result) {

        $('#HeatGradeDiv').dialog('close');
        $("#Partial_Chem_Analysis").html(result);
        //ajax call I'm trying to get working
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Home/ButtonsPartial",
            success: function (result2) { $("#ButtonsPartial").html(result2); }
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

Here is the controller method I'm calling. When I run it now it is not getting hit.

```
public ActionResult ButtonsPartial()
    {
        ButtonsModel B = new ButtonsModel();
        B.GetData(searchQ);

        return PartialView(B);
    }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Poor man's debugging:  Add an `error: function (response) { // dump response to page here }` to your Ajax call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you attach it to a debugger such as (chrome developer tools or firebug) are you seeing any http or js errors?

It looks like you might need to make it a GET rather than POST...

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Home/ButtonsPartial",
            success: function (result2) { $("#ButtonsPartial").html(result2); }
        });
```

Comment: I just tried that with no success. I'm not even getting anything in the firebug console for that get. I get something for the original post though.

Comment: I had something in the wrong spot, but having 'POST' instead of 'GET' was an issue. Thanks!